# What's this linguistic phenomenon in English speaking?

Tags: english, phonology, phonetics, american-english

> I was enjoying the relaxing vibes that the hotel provided.

When Americans say the above sentence, do they sometimes say "vibes that" in a way that sounds like "vibesat"?

Does it belong to the same phenomenon that "I like him/them" is spoken as "I likeum"?

Does it also happen in other English dialects?

What's the linguistic phenomenon called? Is it a
phonetical or phonological one?

Comment: I do not know if Americans have this pronunciation, and it is not listed in [Pronunciation of English ⟨th⟩](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_of_English_⟨th⟩) article (read at least section "Dialectal realizations"), but it could be some example of [aphaeresis / apheresis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apheresis) or [procope](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/procope).

Comment: You are cross posting, which is highly discouraged, maybe even not allowed.  I already gave you the answer here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/347871/whats-this-linguistic-phonetic-or-phonologic-phenomenon-called/347875#347875 It's an example of connected speech. All languages have connected speech that is different from writing. This has zero to with AmE. All varieties of English have connected speech.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a dupe of a question already answered on ELL

Answer (score 1):

It is called phonetic reduction and it is not restricted to the English language and its dialects. It appears universally in environments where some word is very probable to appear (i.e., it has a low surprisal). In fact, the word *that* is so redundant in the context of the example that it can be dropped entirely.

The phenomenon is studied in phonetics, and a researcher active in the field is Bernd Möbius from Saarland University.

Disclaimer: The author of this answer has connections to Saarland University, but is not working in the group of Möbius.